# Connect several sim800l with external power supply to the uart of ip4 and floating ground

Tags: gpio, power, uart, gsm, cooling

I am creating a circuit with several sim00l connected to different UARTs each with its own external power. But I'm curious if having other objects like cooler-fan connected to other GND of the rpi would not affect the functionality of my sim800l regarding what is known as ' floating ground or FG'. Here is what I plan to implement https://ibb.co/KXxCXFf. In the same way I would like to know if my common ground connection between sim800l and rip4 would work De Thank you. [image]

Comment: you must have a common ground, unless you use opto-isolators ... your configuration looks ok ... how is the RPi powered?

Comment: Thanks, I am powering the rpi with an external power supply (5V and 3.0 A).

Answer (score 1):

Well friends if the circuit worked, is more I edited it by changing the lipo battery power supply for power regulated with lm2596 and a 4700uf capacitor for each sim800l module. Thanks